# how write class/def/input in terminal in Python

Tags: python, function, class, input

I am adding car function entry to the class but it is not working.

```py
    class car():
      def __init__(self,speed,engine,color):
         self.speed = speed
         #ı add speed
         self.engine = engine
         #ı add engine
         self.color = color
         #ı add color
         print("new car add")
    car1 = car(233,23,"red")
    car2 = car(300,59,"yellow")
    car3 = car(32,23,"blue")
    a = int(input("car number: "))
    b = str(input("type : speed , engine , color: ")) 
    a = str(a)
    #make car + a
    #maybe here is broken
    no = "car" + a
    nu = no + "." + b
    print(nu)
```

How do I get the color of car #1 when `a == 1` and `b == "color"`?

Comment: What's not working? Please add to your question the expected output and (*as text*) the actual output.

Comment: now what i want is car1 color but direct code output car1.color

Answer (score 0):

1. You want a *list* of `car` objects, not a bunch of numbered variables.

   ```
   cars = [car(233,23,"red"),
           car(300,59,"yellow"),
           car(32,23,"blue")
   ]
   ```
2. Use `getattr` to get an attribute using a variable that contains the name of the attribute.

   ```
   >>> a = 1; b = "color"; getattr(cars[a], b)
   'red'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In the case that `a='1'` and `b='color'`:

then

```py
nu = "car1.color"
```

This is a string, but what you would like is for python to evaluate and run it as an expression.

You can use `eval()` to do this. Try:

```py
print(eval(nu))
```

However, I would suggest a better approach is using a list as @chepner suggested, or a dictionary.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice